# decodeAudioData hogs memory

Tags: web-audio-api

Each time you decode an audio file, Chrome tab's memory usage grows for about 100 MB (for a typical-sized MP3 file).

`OfflineAudioContext.decodeAudioData`, on the contrary, behaves very differently: it releases the memory after decoding a file.

Why does the "online" `AudioContext` keep all this memory intact?

Comment: Just a guess, but I think this is just due to the decoding output. What might have been a 5 MB MP3 can get really huge when you convert it to 32-bit PCM at 44.1kHz (which is what the Web Audio API uses).

A 4-minute stereo MP3 would get up around 80 MB of decoded audio data (roughly 10 MB per minute of mono audio).

Comment: @KevinEnnis, that's absolutely understandable. But why does it keep all these data *after* decoding? It's not in JavaScript, I checked via devtools memory snapshots.

Comment: It's in an isolated test: I'm not storing a reference to the decoded buffer anywhere, I'm just decoding a file and exiting.

Comment: Ahhh, okay. I didn't realize you weren't holding on to the decoded buffer. That is weird then.

Comment: Even offlineAudioContext leaks memory, I opened issue here https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=554025

Comment: @Esailija thanks, good to know!